vscode server очень сильно использует оперативную память сервера
У меня CentOS 7, на борту 128 ГБ оперативной памяти, и при подключение через vscode по SSH Remote, vscode server очень сильно начинает нагружать сервер. С каждым разом все больше и больше начинает использовать оперативную память.
Я вывел через htop и вижу большое количество /root/.vscode-server/ и так далее, и что она использует как раз таки память(На скриншоте видно).
Вопрос, как мне сделать так, чтобы не использовать больше памяти vscode-server?


Вы не туда смотрите. htop показывает потоки, а не процессы; столбец VIRT - адресное пространство, а не потребялемую память. Единственная проблема на скриншоте - запуск vscode из-под root

Но в любом случае, я вижу как идет нагрузка на сервер именно на оперативную память из за vscode-server, что мне нужно сделать чтобы как-то ограничить используемую память

На скриншоте потребеление 0.1% - не существенное. Хотите ограничить память - запускайте в контейнере с лимитами

Why is VSCode Consuming 1 TB of Virtual Memory?

Каждый перезапуск будет прибавлять потребление озу, возможно поэтому у вас такое огромное потребление.
Можно выполнить команду 'pkill vscode' на удаленном сервере.
Либо, на локальной машине, можно выполнить команду из vscode: 'f1' далее 'Kill VS Code Server on Host' , далее выбрать нужный хост.
